# Secure way to run Flash on Chrome?

Tags: chrome, flash

I kinda addicted to Little Big Snake, an online game that requires Flash. I'm trying to find a secure way to play this game on Ubuntu using Chrome.

I tried Firejail but the game is very laggy with it. The only thing I do for now to make it more secure is enable AppArmor. I hope you have better suggestions for me. For instance, can Incognito mode in Chrome mitigate zero-day attacks on Flash player?

Comment: What do you mean by "a secure way"? What are the threats that you are afraid of?

Comment: if the game's not malicious, what are you concerned about? isn't flash click to run in chrome?

Comment: "what are you concerned about?" flash zero day attacks

Answer (score 2):

"btw Incognito mode in chrome can mitigate zero-day attacks on flash player?"

No, no way. No. I have no idea how you figured that.

As flash is notoriously insecure, there is not much you can do other than sequestering the browser from the PC. Your best bet is probably virtualization. Either run a VM, or use Qubes, on OS that does that for you. Alternatively, you can try using OS run from a USB memory stick, that can not write to your HDD such as Tails. Without being able to read form/write to your disk, there is nothing very harmful it can do.

Comment: "No, no way. No. I have no idea how you figured that."               i thought maybe it can exit the attacker session or delete any files he try to upload on my computer, after i exit incognito mode it delete all files

Comment: @justlinx69 Sorry if too dramatic, but that sound as a very dangerous misconception. Believing something is secure when it is not is a terrible thing, so if you heard/read that somewhere, you may want to point it out as being incorrect.

Comment: @justlinx69 Incognito deletes cookies and history, but not downloaded files. And more importantly, flash vulnerabilities can allow viruses to bypass chrome altogether, so even if it deleted all files normally, it would not delete the virus as the virus would be able to bypass that.

Comment: yeah i just read again the google chrome help article. i just kind a tired of trying make it more secure after experiment with docker and firejail

Comment: @justlinx69 Well, if you trust the developer of the game and the site it is hosted on (+ use https), than it may not be as insecure to just go for it and play the game without taking paranoid precautions :) Of course as long as it is a personal PC with nothing too important on it.

Comment: You may want to download the game, incase the site serving it gets compromised